# Unique elements from a list according to a subset of fields

Tags: list, haskell, duplicates, unique

Given a record like

```hs
data Foo = Foo { fooName :: Text, fooAge :: Int, fooCity :: Text }
```

With a list of such elements, is there a function to remove duplicates on a subset of fields only, on the model of this hypothetical `removeDupBy` function?

```hs
foos =
  [
    Foo "john" 32 "London",
    Foo "joe" 18 "New York",
    Foo "john" 22 "Paris",
    Foo "john" 32 "Madrid",
    Foo "joe" 17 "Los Angeles",
    Foo "joe" 18 "Berlin"
  ]

> removeDupBy (\(Foo f) -> (fooName, fooAge)) foos 
[
    Foo "john" 32 "London",
    Foo "joe" 18 "New York",
    Foo "john" 22 "Paris",
    Foo "joe" 17 "Los Angeles"
]
```

I could implement my own but would prefer using one from a well-established library, which will probably be much more performant and be much more resilient against edge cases. I was thinking of using `nub` but I'm not sure how to map the actual `Foo` elements to the tuples `(fooName, fooAge)` that `nub` would filter out.

Comment: [`nubOrdOn`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.4.1/docs/Data-Containers-ListUtils.html#v:nubOrdOn) from [containers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers).

Comment: Just found about [the history of `nubOrd` / `nubOrdOn`](https://github.com/nh2/haskell-ordnub)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are dealing with only strings and numbers, you can use the `Ord` instance to remove duplicates efficiently, or even `Hashable`, which allows practically constant-time lookups.

Some functions which exactly match your desired signature are:

1. [`nubOrdOn`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.4.1/docs/Data-Containers-ListUtils.html#v:nubOrdOn) from the [containers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers) package

```
Data.Containers.ListUtils> nubOrdOn (\f -> (fooName f, fooAge f)) foos
```

2. [`hashNubOn`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/witherable-0.4.1/docs/Witherable.html#v:hashNubOn) from the [witherable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/witherable) package

```
Witherable> hashNubOn (\f -> (fooName f, fooAge f)) foos
```

You may find other options by searching on [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/) for [`(a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%28a%20-%3E%20b%29%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D)

If you need to do many operations like this, you may prefer to use `Map` or `HashMap` directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [nubBy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-List.html#v:nubBy):

```
Prelude Data.List> nubBy (\x y -> (fooName x, fooAge x) == (fooName y, fooAge y)) foos
[Foo {fooName = "john", fooAge = 32, fooCity = "London"},
 Foo {fooName = "joe", fooAge = 18, fooCity = "New York"},
 Foo {fooName = "john", fooAge = 22, fooCity = "Paris"},
 Foo {fooName = "joe", fooAge = 17, fooCity = "Los Angeles"}]
```

(Output formatted for enhanced readability)

Comment: This algorithm is O(n^2), but it could be O(n log n) if the `Ord` or `Hashable` instances were used.

Comment: @4castle would you use `Ord`/`Hashable` with `nubBy` or would it need using `nubOrdOn`?

Comment: @Jivan It would have to be with a different function, like `nubOrdOn`, or you could use a `Map`/`HashMap` (insert all, and then read out the values)